# Start a script by internal endpoint

Tags: azure

I upload many cmd script to Role instance, then I want to use interal endpoint,  excute a cmd script by admin on all of instances.

Can I rechieve that?
And I　want to upload a script to all my instance, what's the best way to do that?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to distribute the script via Azure Storage - most likely Blob Storage will the the best.

Option one is that you upload the script to one instance and once the upload is complete that instance uploads the script into blob storage and the other instances download the script.

Option two is that you upload the script to blob storage and then all instances download the script from there.